# MTL algebra 'prelinearity' condition etymology

Tags: logic, terminology, monoid

[According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_t-norm_logic#MTL-algebras) the *prelinearity condition* of a monoidal t-norm logic is expressed as $(x\implies y) \vee (y\implies x) = 1$.

As far as I know, the 'pre' prefixed version of a rule or classification is indicative of a condition that's just slightly different from (weaker than?) the un-prefixed rule (e.g. pre-Hilbert space).

Is there such a relationship between 'prelinearity' as used here and some 'linearity' axiom and, if there is, what is it?

Comment: In partial orders, the word "linear" is also used as a synonym of being a total order (i.e., a chain). This is the appropiate sense to understand prelinearity in the MTL setting; the reason is that the variety of MTL algebras (i.e., prelinear FLew algebras) is generated by chains. To sum up, no realtionship with the use of the word "linear" in "Linear Algebras"

Comment: @boumol: your comment looks like the answer to me!

Comment: @boumol I'm with Rob on this - please put that into an answer so I can accept it! (preferably with a little more explanation about how the algebras are generated by chains)

Comment: @user: The generation is done in the usual way of universal algebra, which is the HSP theorem. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra#Some_basic_theorems

Answer (score 0):

A lattice, L, is linear if for each $x,y\in L$ either $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x$. It may be noted that any linear lattice is prelinear but the converse is not true in general. Hence the prefix "pre" is justified.